# Does rspec use WEBrick to run tests?

Tags: rspec, tdd, thin, webrick

I have a Ruby on Rails project that was running into an ArgumentError 2 for 0 problem which was solved by using Thin instead of WEBrick. When I run rspec, I'm getting the same error. Does rspec use WEBRick to run tests? If so, is there a way to make it run Thin instead?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of rails/rspec that is being used or what type of rspec tests is involved, so it is not possible to provide more specific information. If you are writing request/integration specs, then capybara can be used in conjunction with rspec as it loads thin by default with webrick as a fallback.